# What's the QGIS Map Management Tool?

Tags: qgis, census

I'm using a walkthrough for QGIS that requires I use the Map Management tool to open a zip file. The walkthrough makes it seem that this is a window that opens automatically when QGIS opens, which doesn't happen for me. I'm using the US Census Bureau's GUPS application.
This is the first time I've ever used QGIS... is there anyone that can give me some guidance to locate the Map Management tool? I can clarify/re-phrase this if necessary.

Comment: Hello, could you give the link to the walk-through you are talking about?

Comment: The PDF is available here:
http://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/partnerships/bas/17_BASRespondentGuide_GUPS.pdf
You should also be able to find links to download the data in the PDF, as well

Comment: When you open up the software does it come up with the GUPs branding or does it look like standard QGIS?

Comment: It appears to be the standard QGIS branding.

Comment: Same issue, couldn't find the button referred to by ktom but did find a document explaining how to ensure the GUPS Map Management plugin is configured correctly on local machine and that the plugin is chosen through plugin management to be installed on the toolbar
https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial/rdo/about/2020-census-program/Phase2/Steps_to_install_GUPS_manually.pdf

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134530)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have gotten a constructive answer to this question, but I came across your post when I had the same concern.  In the 2020 Census Local Update of Census Addresses Operation (LUCA) Respondent Guide, on p. 35/186 of the pdf, there is a Function/Description table of buttons on the GUPS toolbar.  The Map Management button there is the only way I have found to open this window again.  I have circled the button with red on the attached image file.  Hopefully this is helpful to you and answers your question.  You'll see the GUPS version at the top of the image for reference. [image]